# Spree - Render Partial if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, spree, partials

I'm trying to render a partial on home page. Code is a follows:

```
<%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/slider' %>
```

The thing is I want it to render/show the partial only if I'm on the home page .To summaries for a particular page/pages only.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional for deciding whether the partial should be rendered:

```
<%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/slider' if @slider %>
```

The condition could be an instance variable (e.g. `@slider`) which can be set from the view (when not set, it remains nil by default):

```
<% @slider = true %>
```

Now the partial will only be rendered if `@slider` has been explicitly set to true in the view or in the controller.